# input tag bigger size and text in input tag centered vertically

Tags: css, input, textinput

This is the form I need to do:

[image]

For now I'm in this point:

[image]

As you can observe I need to create the input buttons bigger. Otherwise visually it will not work. My question would be how to create the input buttons bigger vertically and the input text stay centered vertically in middle of the box.

CSS solution would be the best.

This is my html code if it helps:

```
<form name="bookingform" action="form-to-email.php" method="post">
                            <div id="form_box" class="gradient">
                                <div id="center_box">
                                    <h3>WANT TO BOOK ME?</h3>
                                    <div id="form_data">
                                        <br>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="Company name" name="company" /></td>
                                                <td class="tdright"><input type="text" value="Name" name="name" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="Telephone" name="telephone" /></td>
                                                <td class="tdright"><input type="text" value="Email" name="email" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="text" value="Booking date" name="date" /></td>
                                                <td><input type="button" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div id="form_text">
                                        <br>
                                        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message">Your text...</textarea>
                                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" name="submit" />
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="image" src="" name="Send" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[type=button] {
    height: 35px;      /* increase the height */
    line-height: 35px; /* vertically align the text */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7rxD/)

Comment: Is this cross-browser friendly?